# Detect tap on GMSPolyline in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, polygon, polyline

I'm struggling with detecting a tap on a GMSPolyline drawn on my Google map, it works just fine with GMSpolygones, but the same approach doesn't seem to work with polyline. My current approach, which works for polygones, is:

```
if (GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinate, polygon.path!, false)) {
    ...
}
```

Any suggestions how to detect taps on a polyline? Or just close to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to their API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_overlay#a45005ec17da8c14bd1978f5cf19d91c7), `GMSPolyline` inherits from `GMSOverlay` which means a `GMSPolyline` has the property `tappable`. So you'd want something like this

```
let polyLine: GMSPolyline = GMSPolyline(path: newPath)
polyLine.isTappable = true
polyline.zIndex = 0
polyline.map = yourGoogleMap
```

Then your `GMSMapViewDelegate` should notify you of the tap anywhere within the `GMSPolyline` layer with this function

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay)
{
  print(overlay.zindex)
  print("User Tapped Layer: \(overlay)")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `isTappable` property of GMSPolyline.

> isTappable
>
> If this overlay should cause tap notifications.
>
> polyline.isTappable = true

`GMSPolyline` inherits from `GMSOverlay`. So to detect tap on overlays `GMSMapViewDelegate` provides a delegate method:

> - mapView:didTapOverlay: Called after an overlay has been tapped.

Whenever the polyline is tapped, the `GMSMapViewDelegate` method `didTapOverlay` is called

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
        //Write your code here
    }
```

Also, this method can be used for `GMSPolygon` since it also inherits from `GMSOverlay`.

For further information refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#a3a2bf2ff4481528f931183cb364c0f4b

Comment: Curious how this will look in SwiftUI being the map is in a UIRepresentable?